# input checkbox : Not able to call controller function

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, css

I have below component, however I am not getting console logs from the  method, I need to get the value of the checkbox getting called.

```
                        <ul class="ks-cboxtags">
                        <li ><span onclick="{!c.addStatusFilter}"><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxOne" value="Paid"  /><label for="checkboxOne">Paid</label></span></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxTwo" value="Pending" onchange="{!c.addStatusFilter}" /><label for="checkboxTwo">Pending</label></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxThree" value="Rejected" onchange="{!c.addStatusFilter}" /><label for="checkboxThree">Rejected</label></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFour" value="Declined" onchange="{!c.addStatusFilter}" /><label for="checkboxFour">Declined</label></li>
                    </ul>
```

I have tried:
span
onchange
onclick

Below is code from controller js

```
addStatusFilter:function(component,event,helper){
    alert('Add filter');
    console.log('Inside add Status Filter');
    //var btnValue = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    console.log('btnValue---->'+btnValue);
    applyStatusFilter(component,event,helper);
},
addStatusFilter:function(component,event,helper){
}
```

Comment: You didn't actually share the method, so we can't really help you. Generally speaking, this works just fine. If you [edit] your question to include more code, we can help.

Comment: Hi sir, added code. I have some custom styles as  well.https://codepen.io/quinlo/pen/ReMRXz?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=5cffa5965fc918dd922ab90f776e4f10a5f6bed2-1591356867-0-AZt42J07vJPWU7qF2-ti6OjU_0qBFoQoXiLpm1x6bORZn28pEgnCTizmeRbvEOImwqLgYVbE2bApul__Qb992tr25f-Mg4KOwLVf6qgGlXmEcZQwHxgmmy2XSsmMW7OQkXIjAMvTah09SlEG4IWzHA7PWc0gueuIkSEs_9U31DlrD6Gn-dMxitHO9r6u6CzDk3GmHaKYdyCcHCINIAzTL5XyraUZ7EiJC1NksN04NWHg29QXzVIUwgXPYKBBuzs-EqJ7rpkCAMpBf8R1WAWhTIT_LrToV1BN6S8Y_83w4yuVKQQZV1u1YZTcyBW1dZ4eL3lukuHXJmurBdaj5enmW1h-t-Nw8BMPWRelZU-YO4Oq

Comment: anyways I got the issue,I have two methods with same name.. I changed the name of second, it's working now. @sfdcfox any idea how can I load icons in css. I have asked separate question for it with FontAwesome titles https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308467/fontawesome-css-not-bale-to-use-in-lightning-component