# FontAwesome CSS - not able to use in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I am trying to use some `FontAwesome` icons like this:

```
.THIS ul.ks-cboxtags li label::before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 2px;
    content: "\f000"; //THis is I am trying to use
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

However,  I am not able to load icons
I have downloaded the zip from FontAwesome website,and uploaded it as the static resource.

and then used this

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.FontAwesome}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import "Font Awesome" into your css after you upload it as a static resource.

It should look similar to this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFontAwesome';
    src: url('resource/FontAwesome/fontawesome-free-5.13.0-web/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff') format('woff');
}

.THIS ul.ks-cboxtags li label::before {
    font-family: myFontAwesome;
    content: "\f000";
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 2px;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

In the above example inside `@font-face` you choose what to name the font-family. I set it to `'myFontAwesome'`. That's a name you give to the font after you reference it. You can call it anything you want. However when you reference the `font-family:` in your `.THIS ul.ks-cboxtags li label::before` element later you need to give it the exact same name you chose when you imported the font.

Comment: so... I don't have the fonts folder, so I used webfonts folder... I have some woff files. I am trying this..............src: url('resource/fontAwesome/fontawesome-free-5.13.0-web/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff') format('woff');

Comment: What name did you give to your static resource when you uploaded font awesome?

Comment: FontAwesome... this is the name I gave

Comment: I am not sure if this will matter but try changing the src to `src: url('resource/FontAwesome/fontawesome-free-5.13.0-web/fonts/font-awesome-webfont.woff') format('woff');`

See in the original example I had `resource/fontAwesome`, camelcase. Try to change that to `FontAwesome` like the name you gave your static resource.

Comment: there is no fonts folder, there is webfonts folder, but it doesn't have the  file you mentioned

Comment: or should I download the version you have mentioned :) let me try that

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem. Let me try your code in my sandbox.

Comment: @mvk1991 In your browser press CTRL+SHIFT+I to go to the dev console. Go to the network tab. Then refresh your component. Look for `fa-regular-400.woff`. What color is that showing in?

Comment: I can't find it. Have loaded the static resource incorrectly?

Comment: In Console.. I searched.. it shows.. Failed to decode downloaded font: followed by the url... Which we have..

Comment: There is an error as well.. Refused to apply style from.. because the MIME type zip is not a supported MIME type.

Comment: Okay, erase everything after the `.com/` in the url of your component page. So basically you want to end up with something like `your-domain.lightning.force.com/`. Now append this to the url `resource/FontAwesome/fontawesome-free-5.13.0-web/fonts/font-awesome-webfont.woff`. Is your browser downloading the `.woff` file?

Comment: No... it didn't download, just showed site cannot be reached

Comment: Oops sorry.. I used this "resource/FontAwesome/fontawesome-free-5.13.0-web/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff" this is  in my system, it downloaded the file

Answer (score 1):

To use Font Awesome icons with Aura components:

1. Create the static resource: in Static Resources create a new resource. For example, "FontAwesomeFree", and upload the zip file from Font Awesome. Keep in mind that the maximum file size is 5Mb, so you might have to re-compress it.
2. In the component require the all.css file. You need to specify the path to the file inside the zip file like this:

```
 <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.FontAwesomeFree + '/fontawesome/css/all.css'}" />
```

[Here is the Resources reference.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_resource_value_provider.htm)

3. Then you can use the icons like:

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

https://emojipedia.org/

Problem is my other question is unncessarily closed. my question there was simple, how to use lightning icons in the css file of the lightning component.