# Need to use icon in css (dynamic)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

I am trying to use this checkbox button structure in my component

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="ks-cboxtags">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxOne" value="Rainbow Dash"><label for="checkboxOne">Rainbow Dash</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxTwo" value="Cotton Candy" checked><label for="checkboxTwo">Cotton Candy</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxThree" value="Rarity" checked><label for="checkboxThree">Rarity</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFour" value="Moondancer"><label for="checkboxFour">Moondancer</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFive" value="Surprise"><label for="checkboxFive">Surprise</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSix" value="Twilight Sparkle" checked><label for="checkboxSix">Twilight
                    Sparkle</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSeven" value="Fluttershy"><label for="checkboxSeven">Fluttershy</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxEight" value="Derpy Hooves"><label for="checkboxEight">Derpy Hooves</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxNine" value="Princess Celestia"><label for="checkboxNine">Princess
                    Celestia</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxTen" value="Gusty"><label for="checkboxTen">Gusty</label></li>
    <li class="ks-selected"><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxEleven" value="Discord"><label for="checkboxEleven">Discord</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxTwelve" value="Clover"><label for="checkboxTwelve">Clover</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxThirteen" value="Baby Moondancer"><label for="checkboxThirteen">Baby
                    Moondancer</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFourteen" value="Medley"><label for="checkboxFourteen">Medley</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFifteen" value="Firefly"><label for="checkboxFifteen">Firefly</label></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #FFEFBA;
    /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF, #FFEFBA);
    /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF, #FFEFBA);
    /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

}

.container {
    max-width: 640px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li{
  display: inline;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li label{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
    border: 2px solid rgba(139, 139, 139, .3);
    color: #adadad;
    border-radius: 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 3px 0px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    transition: all .2s;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li label {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li label::before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 2px;
    content: "\f067";
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    content: "\f00c";
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    border: 2px solid #1bdbf8;
    background-color: #12bbd4;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all .2s;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: absolute;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label {
  border: 2px solid #e9a1ff;
}
```

Now it has this css, which uses the icon from FontAwesome, I am unable to use this.
I tried it in static resource however, I am not able to see the icons.

I just need two icons

- utility:add
- utility:check

I tried writing them, however the direct display.

I am putting the concerned css.

```
    .THIS ul.ks-cboxtags li label::before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 2px;
    content: "\f000";
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Did you import font awesome in your CSS?

Comment: I added it into static resource,and use ltngRequire

Comment: <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.FontAwesome}" />

Comment: is it possible to include it from cdn?

Comment: Would have been better to edit your original question instead of posting the same in the new question: [FontAwesome CSS - not able to use in lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308467/fontawesome-css-not-bale-to-use-in-lightning-component)

Comment: actually in this question I am looking for how to use lightning icon utility:add in the css

Comment: fontawesome-free-5.13.0-web .. this was the file I downloaded

Comment: @mvk1991 Yep, seems like the icons' content values are matching. Here's a cheat sheet for that version of font-awesome if you need to reference other icons as well: https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Font_Awesome.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index

Comment: Arthlete is right, you are not using the proper icon name. @mvk1991 You may be confused with SLDS icons, why not use the native [SLDS icons](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/#utility)?

Comment: Raul, that's I don't know how to use, I just need two simple icons, I tried writing... content: "utility:add" ... it shows the text, instead of icon

Comment: thanks Arthlete.. I  tried  use fa-check as well.. it shows the text.

Comment: Not sure,why this is closed, if someone reads the question carefully (skipping all the css files) I am asking how to  use lightning icons in css file of the lightning component.

Comment: Part of the reason is that your post does not contain a clear, concise, fully descriptive question. If you can pose a single interrogative that contains all details needed and nothing else, that helps tremendously. You have a few places you come close, but don't quite hit the mark. You are also missing one of the most important lines in your example (where you include the resource). You also have a lot of extra markup which makes it a bit harder to read, though that is not a blocker per se.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Actually I just add a link to a codepen (just for reference), I guess someone edited it to convert them into code, which I thought is a good help. I guess I should have mentioned my point as the first line,then could have given the reference. Anyways, I'm still curious how can use utility:check in css file. I solved my problem with emojipedia, but that's just a workaround I guess.