# How to make font-awesome icons work on Lightning Web Components?

Tags: javascript, css, static-resources, lightning-web-components

Downloaded the latest version of the Font Awesome Icons as a .zip file, I extract the files and uploaded the file all.css as a static resource in my scratch org.

2. Below is my html

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
//For the above tag only square shows up but not the icon 
<ul>
<li><a class="fab fa-facebook-square" href="https://www.facebook.com/michiganalumni"></a></li>
<li><a class="fab fa-twitter" href="https://twitter.com/michiganalumni"></a></li>
<li><a class="fab fa-instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/michiganalumni"></a></li>
<li><a class="fab fa-linkedin-in" href="https://www.linkedin.com/groups/3435"></a></li>
<li><a class="fab fa-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/c/AlumniAssociationUM"></a></li>
</ul>
```

3. Here is my JS File

```
import FontsforSocialMedia from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/FontAwesome';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

renderedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, FontsforSocialMedia + '/all.css')
        ]).catch(error => {
             console.log(error);

        });
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here, this should do it for you: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308467/fontawesome-css-not-able-to-use-in-lightning-component/308500#308500

Answer (score 1):

*HTML File:-*

```
<template>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
</template>
```

*JavaScript File:-*

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import Fontawesome from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/BootstapCDN';



export default class PortfolioFooter extends LightningElement {
    renderedCallback() {
        
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, Fontawesome + '/css/all.css')
            ]).then(() => {
                console.log( 'Files loaded' );
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log( error.body.message );
        });

    } 
}
```

Note:- If you want to use the font awesome library in LWC Component for that you have to upload a Zip file of the font awesome library into a static resource.